# Link to external object using the right (target-specific) compiler

Tags: rust, linker, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I have a Rust crate that is targeting AVR. If I do a `cargo build`, it fails at linking, which is expected because I will need to add an extra object (compiled from C) to it. However, the error message shows that Cargo has correctly picked up from the target definition that it should use `avr-gcc` for linking:

```
"avr-gcc" "-mmcu=atmega328p" ....
  = note: chirp8-avr/target/avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328/release/deps/chirp8_avr-e38dd93db57fe6d7.chirp8_avr.dlqaoark-cgu.0.rcgu.o: In function `main':
          chirp8_avr.dlqaoark-cgu.0:(.text.main+0x18a): undefined reference to `font_rom_size'
          chirp8_avr.dlqaoark-cgu.0:(.text.main+0x19e): undefined reference to `read_font_rom'
          chirp8_avr.dlqaoark-cgu.0:(.text.main+0x1b4): undefined reference to `prog_rom_size'
          chirp8_avr.dlqaoark-cgu.0:(.text.main+0x1c6): undefined reference to `read_prog_rom'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So the next logical step is to add my external C source to the crate. From what I understand, [`cc`](https://crates.io/crates/cc) is exactly the crate for that. So let's try that: I add `cc` to my `[build-dependencies]`, and write the following `build.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        // .flag("-mmcu=atmega328p").pic(false)
        .file("src/rom.c")
        .compile("rom");
}
```

If I now try building again, this fails because Cargo suddenly seems to have forgotten to use `avr-gcc`, and is instead trying to use the system's default C compiler:

```
  running: "cc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-o" "chirp8-avr/target/avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328/release/build/chirp8-avr-fd0f12cc4390c66b/out/src/rom.o" "-c" "src/rom.c"
  cargo:warning=src/rom.c:1:10: fatal error: avr/pgmspace.h: No such file or directory
  cargo:warning=    1 | #include <avr/pgmspace.h>
  cargo:warning=      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=compilation terminated.
  exit code: 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the target platform not picked up correctly by Cargo?

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [the cc crate's Readme](https://crates.io/crates/cc):

> This crate calls out to the most relevant compiler for a platform, for example using `cl` on MSVC.

Inspecting [the source](https://docs.rs/cc/1.0.70/src/cc/lib.rs.html#2093-2276) reveals that the cc crate does this with some hard-coded logic for certain statically known host/target combinations.  Unfortunately, avr is not a target for which it knows to use `avr-gcc`.

The Readme also states:

> ### External configuration via environment variables
>
> To control the programs and flags used for building, the builder can
> set a number of different environment variables.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - `CC` - the actual C
>   compiler used. Note that this is used as an exact executable name, so
>   (for example) no extra flags can be passed inside this variable, and
>   the builder must ensure that there aren't any trailing spaces. This
>   compiler must understand the `-c` flag. For certain `TARGETs`, it also is
>   assumed to know about other flags (most common is `-fPIC`).
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> Each of these variables can also be supplied with certain prefixes and
> suffixes, in the following prioritized order:
>
> 1. `<var>_<target>` - for example, `CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`
> 2. `<var>_<target_with_underscores>` - for example,
>    `CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu`
> 3. `<build-kind>_<var>` - for example, `HOST_CC`
>    or `TARGET_CFLAGS`
> 4. `<var>` - a plain `CC`, `AR` as above.
>
> If none of these
> variables exist, `cc-rs` uses built-in defaults

Therefore, I suggest adding to your `build.rs`:

```rust
std::env::set_var("CC_avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328", "avr-gcc");
```